# in JpaRepository if one parameter is common for many query method then how to make as good as possible in Repository and in Service also

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    public List<User> findById(long id);

    public List<User> findByEmail(String email);

    public List<User> findByEmailAndCode(String email, Code code);

    public List<User> findByEmailAndClassType(String email, ClassType code);

}

public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    public List<user> fetchByClassType(ClassType ct) {
        return userRepo.findByEmailAndClassType("email", ct);
    }

}
```

> here email need to fetch once how to avoid it many time to go on database or any other solution in controller it need to give again and again in each request mapping ...suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a bunch of similar repository methods you could go for **specifications**.

See the doc here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

You have to extend JpaSecificationExecutor:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
    ...
}
```

Then you will get a findAll() method that accepts a Specification.

Create a specification like:

```
 public static Specification<Customer> isLongTermCustomer() {
    return new Specification<Customer>() {
      public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Customer> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
            CriteriaBuilder builder) {

         LocalDate date = new LocalDate().minusYears(2);
         return builder.lessThan(root.get(_Customer.createdAt), date);
      }
    };
  }
```

Or if you don't like the JPA Criteria API you could use **QueryDSL** as well:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl

Comment: its nice solution helps in search

Comment: but the thing is like if findBySubject(role,subject)  findByClassType(role,classtype) etc here each time roles is required in that case what is convenient way please suggest